# How to display a specific category using a custom Query?

Tags: wpdb

Hi I want to display a specific category from a custom query in WordPress. My code works fine and it gets the latest 4 posts, but what I want now is to retrieve a specific category. My code is below thanks :

```
global $wpdb;

$posts = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT ID, post_title AS title, post_excerpt AS excerpt FROM '.$wpdb->posts.' WHERE post_type = "post" AND post_status = "publish" ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 4');
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, WordPress provides better ways to query with database. You should not make your query directly with `$wpdb` unless it's absolutely necessary. You should use `WP_Query` and `get_posts()` instead to receive data from WordPress database. If you want to read more about it, [read here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts). @Rarst provided great explanation on better ways to make query in WordPress.

Now I am going to use `WP_Query` to display 4 latest posts from category id 22. In the following parameters you can specify category ID in `cat` or you can use `category_name` instead but then you will have to provide a category slug as value (not category name).

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'cat' => '22',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
    );

    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on continuing on this path using SQL queries, you should first understand how taxonomy terms connect to posts:

- `$wpdb->posts.ID` <--> `$wpdb->term_relationships.object_id`
- `$wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id` <--> `$wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id`
- `$wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id` <--> `$wpdb->terms.term_id`

With this in mind, and assuming you're providing the $taxonomy (string) and $term_slug (string) parameters for the category you're filtering by, I envision your code being written as:

```
function get_top_posts_by_term($taxonomy = 'category', $term_slug = '')
{
    if(empty($term_slug)) {
        // Can't continue without valid inputs
        return FALSE;
    }
    global $wpdb;

    $query = $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT 
                p.ID,
                p.post_title AS title,
                p.post_excerpt AS excerpt
            FROM $wpdb->posts p
                INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships rel
                    ON p.ID = rel.object_id
                INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tax
                    ON rel.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
                INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms t
                    ON tax.term_id = t.term_id
            WHERE p.post_type = 'post'
                AND p.post_status = 'publish'
                AND tax.taxonomy = %s
                AND t.slug = %s
            ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT 4;",
        $taxonomy, // the first %s (tax.taxonomy)
        $term_slug // the second %s (t.slug)
    );
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    return $posts;
}
```

I favor using double-quoted PHP strings when dealing with SQL queries because

- I can use [string interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) with the $wpdb->{table name} variables.
- SQL strings, where used, tend to favor single-quoted strings (I think MySQL is a bit lax in this regard, but it's a good practice to be in).  Double-quoted PHP strings let me use single-quoted string literals without leaving my string or inserting escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

Write your query like this

```
<?php

$query = new WP_Query('category_name=your category name &posts_per_page=-1');

if ( $query ->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        the_content();

    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

You want to query post for a particulate category. Therefor you need to define a custom query. `WP_Query()` do that . Just setup parameter into `WP_Query()` . You can also follow Robert hue's answer. Do you clear?